# Operators "AND" "OR" SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Hello I'm trying to transform this code from SQL to C# using Linq

The SQL code is like this:

```
SELECT N.Name,N.Unit,N.Typee,ID,NOTE 
FROM Table_A N join Table_B A on (N.ID = A.ID) 
join NotasQL G on ((N.Not1 = G.CODE) or (N.Not2 = G.CODE) ) 
join Attributes X on (A.AppID= X.AppID)
```

This Code is running fine in SQL with the expected result, but when I'm trying to replicate this on C# I don't know how to do the OR part, this is what I have so far:

```
var Select = (from A in context.Table_A 
              from B in context.Table_B 
              from E in context.NotasQLs
              from D in context.Attributes 
             where (String.Compare(A.ID, B.ID, true) == 0 &&
                    String.Compare(B.AppID, D.AppID, true) == 0 
                     &&
                    (String.Compare(A.Not1, E.CODE, true) == 0 || 
                      String.Compare(A.Not2, E.CODE, true) == 0))
```

I'm having an application runtime expired because the query is not selecting nothing, if I remove the or condition runs but I need the OR.

Comment: Show the error too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating monadic and aggregate operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns.
5. `JOIN` conditions that aren't all equality tests with `AND` must be handled using `where` clauses outside the join, or with cross product (`from` ... `from` ...) and then `where`
6. `JOIN` conditions that are multiple `AND`ed equality tests between the two tables should be translated into anonymous objects
7. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another from `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
8. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator (`?:`)and a `null` test.
9. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`.
10. Translate *x* `BETWEEN` *low* `AND` *high* to *low* `<=` *x* `&&` *x* `<=` *high*.
11. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
12. `SELECT` fields must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
13. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.

So for your query,

```
var ans = from N in Table_A
          join A in Table_B on N.ID equals A.ID
          from G in NotasQL
          where G.CODE == N.Not1 || G.CODE == N.Not2
          join X in Attributes on A.AppID equals X.AppID
          select new {
              N.Name,
              N.Unit,
              N.Typee,
              N.ID, // ??? not sure table for this column
              G.NOTE // ??? not sure table for this column
          };
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solve my problem