# Query Related to SQL for count records

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, linq, lambda

I have a table for feedback in which i am getting feed backs from customers. he table looks like this

```
ID  Service      Food      Behavior  Environment   OverallExprience  Flight    Date

1   Excellent   VeryGood    Good     Bad            Poor             EK0603  2018-03-29 
2   Excellent   Good      VeryGood   Excellent      Poor             EK0603  2018-03-29
```

All I want from employee is to search the date (from ---> to) and get the brief report which includes

- Number of excellent
- Number of very good
- Number of good
- Number of bad
- poor

for all the given options.
Like in the given Data if Employe selected the date range of **2018-03-29** to **2018-03-29**

So he can see the records like this

```
              Excellent        Very Good    Good     Bad     poor
Service         2                 0           0       0        0

Food            0                 1           1       0        0

Behavior        0                 1           1       0        0

Environment     1                 0           0       1        0
```

Stuck here need help . will be appreciable if the answer is in LINQ query

Comment: So you just want people to code your solutions for you?

Comment: not really , just want to get the hint for query

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start simple and then expand on that.

Comment: select count(*)from Feedbacks group by OverAllExperience doing like this but not getting the desired output in one query

Comment: @FaizanNaeem That doesn't look like LINQ? Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956709/2557128) would help you?

Comment: yeah , just trying in sql right now

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in the question ? If you don't know the answer , vote it down lol

Comment: Have you tried `SUM(Case)` expression? Since you're only dealing with a specific set of columns you want reported on, I think this would be your best solution to start with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/167937/8155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to transpose columns to rows, I guess you need a few UNIONs.
You would probably need a different query for each "category", and for each category you should count how many votes do they get for each option.

Please try this query out, it should do it:

```
SELECT MAX('Service') AS Category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Servive = 'Excellent' THEN 1 END) AS Excellent,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Servive = 'VeryGood' THEN 1 END) AS Very_Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Servive = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Servive = 'Bad' THEN 1 END) AS Bad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Servive = 'Poor' THEN 1 END) AS Poor
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-29' AND '2018-03-29'
UNION
SELECT MAX('Food') AS Category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Food = 'Excellent' THEN 1 END) AS Excellent,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Food = 'VeryGood' THEN 1 END) AS Very_Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Food = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Food = 'Bad' THEN 1 END) AS Bad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Food = 'Poor' THEN 1 END) AS Poor
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-29' AND '2018-03-29'
UNION
SELECT MAX('Behavior') AS Category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Behavior = 'Excellent' THEN 1 END) AS Excellent,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Behavior = 'VeryGood' THEN 1 END) AS Very_Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Behavior = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Behavior = 'Bad' THEN 1 END) AS Bad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Behavior = 'Poor' THEN 1 END) AS Poor
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-29' AND '2018-03-29'
UNION
SELECT MAX('Environment') AS Category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Environment = 'Excellent' THEN 1 END) AS Excellent,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Environment = 'VeryGood' THEN 1 END) AS Very_Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Environment = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Environment = 'Bad' THEN 1 END) AS Bad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Environment = 'Poor' THEN 1 END) AS Poor
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '2018-03-29' AND '2018-03-29'
```

Comment: Thanks (Y) . got the desired output by executing this one